# How to get a list of book writers in freebase

Tags: freebase

I want to get a list of all writers from freebase. I've done an app for musicians and it works nice http://brainbol.com/musicos where I have the next query:

var query = {
'filter':'(all type:/music/artist)',
'key' : 'blablabla...',
'lang':'es'
};

But I can't figure out how to do the same with book writers. Can u help me, thanks!

Comment: In my opinion it's very strange that in a book you have all these properties http://www.freebase.com/book except who has written it.

Comment: I think I get it!!! ... writing "/book/author" instead of "/music/artist" and it seems its working. I don't know how I've arrived at this key because you don't find "author" in the properties of "book".

Comment: Authors write not only books, but short stories, poems, and other written works, so the property is on /book/written_work.  They have the type, as you figured out, /book/author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest `/book/author` is the literary equivalent type of `/music/artist`.  The slight twist is that authors write `/book/written_work` instances, not `/book/book` instances.  If you wanted to constrain your query to authors who had only written books, as opposed to poems or short stories, you'd need to add some additional constraints to your query.

(I know the OP figured this out on their own, but I want this question to stop showing up as unanswered)